# How to print Unicode in Python 2 when LANG=C

Tags: python, unicode

Quite a silly question, I know. Of course normally LANG=C indicates an ASCII terminal
which cannot display Unicode characters. But I nevertheless want to print out the UTF-8 bytes. I use Python 2 (2.6.5 actually)

```
print '\xc3\xa4', u'\xe4'
```

This prints 'ä ä' on a Unicode terminal, but the second string causes an error when executed with LANG=C. I don't want Python to be smart but simply convert u'\xe4' to UTF-8 so it's just '\xc3\xa4' in memory.

I tried all combinations of decode(), encode() and unicode() that I can imagine but it seems I missed the right combination.

What I actually want is reading Unicode charaters through vi's `system()` function, like

```
:echo system('python foo.py')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To encode a `unicode` to utf-8, call `.encode('utf-8')` on it.:

```
>>> u'\xe4'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa4'
```

Comment: Hm ok that works in the with `LANG=C python foo.py` I could swear I tried that one.